# How to make simple_form input field wider with CSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

We are trying to make simple_form input field wider. Here is the simple_form css posted on GitHub:

```
/* ----- SimpleForm Styles ----- */

.simple_form div.input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both; /* Required for Webkit, but not for Gecko */
}

.simple_form label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
}

div.boolean, .simple_form input[type='submit'] {
  margin-left: 120px;
}

div.boolean label, label.collection_radio_buttons {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

label.collection_radio_buttons {
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: -2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.field_with_errors {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}

.simple_form .error {
  clear: left;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.simple_form .hint {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 120px;
  color: #555;
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
}

input.radio {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: -3px;
}

input.check_boxes {
  margin-left: 3px;
  vertical-align: -3px;
}

label.collection_check_boxes {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: -2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

Or in SASS format:

/* ----- SimpleForm Styles ----- */

.simple_form
  div.input
    margin-bottom: 10px
    clear: both

  label
    float: left
    width: 100px
    text-align: right
    margin: 2px 10px

  .error
    clear: left
    color: black
    display: block
    margin-left: 120px

  .hint
    clear: left
    margin-left: 120px
    color: #555
    display: block
    font-style: italic

div.boolean, .simple_form input[type='submit']
  margin-left: 120px

div.boolean label, label.collection_radio_buttons
  float: none
  margin: 0

label.collection_radio_buttons
  margin-right: 10px
  vertical-align: -2px
  margin-left: 2px

.field_with_errors
  background-color: #ff3333

input.radio
  margin-right: 5px
  vertical-align: -3px

input.check_boxes
  margin-left: 3px
  vertical-align: -3px

label.collection_check_boxes
  float: none
  margin: 0
  vertical-align: -2px
  margin-left: 2px
```

We tried a few options in `div input {}` but there was no change with the field width. Not sure which part is for the layout of the input field. How can we make the input field wider by modified the CSS above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
width: 600px:
```

To:

.simple_form div.input {
}

To make it 600px for example. Google "input .width CSS" for more information.

If you only want it applied to text fields use input[type=text]

Comment: Tried and it did not work. Can we specify a percentage instead?

Comment: Can use a percent, yep. I can't comment specifically why it doesn't work without seeing the HTML (or erb HTML) too.

Comment: Realised I've read the CSS wrong. Do this: input { width: 600px: } you can make it more specific with input[type=text] {} for only text fields or give the inputs a class and do input.classname {}

Comment: tried width: 600px; in both .simple_form div.input {} and .simple_form input {} and found no effect on the width.

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS is being loaded at all on the page you are viewing? FireBug for Firefox is a good debugging tool as it'll allow you to see what CSS is being applied - it might be being overridden by other CSS - try adding !important after width "input { width: 600px !important;} - that should stop it being overridden. Do you have a link to the page or something as it could be any number of things without more information.

Comment: I did check the firebug and did not find .simple_form. However I am sure that simple_form css is working because I could use width: under .simple_form label {} to adjust the label width. Also without simple_form css, the format should be ugly.

Comment: Look for class="simple_form" I'm guessing on the form. In any case - do you have a live example otherwise all I can do is suggest possibilities on the dark rather than tell you instantly what the issue is.

Comment: if you tell me what you are looking for, I will take a look. Thanks for the help anyway.